# I want to create a user in SSMS 18 with permission to select, create view, and drop view

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm using the following code, but it's also allowing the use of create table and drop table.

```
CREATE LOGIN usuario WITH PASSWORD = 'Dd123.456';
USE banco;
CREATE USER usuario FOR LOGIN usuario ;

USE banco;
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::dbo TO usuario ;

GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO usuario;
GRANT CONNECT TO usuario;
GRANT ALTER TO usuario;
```

I'm using this code, what's wrong or what's missing?

I tried the code I provided, but the user can still use 'create' and 'drop'.

Comment: The version of SSMS, and that you're using SSMS, is likely irrelevant. It's the data engine (SQL Server) and its version that's important. SSMS 18 supports SQL Server 2008-2019 along with some ofmtber productss such as Azure Synapse.